# EXC_I386_INVOP error when setting SKSpriteNode.phyisicsBody.categoryBitMask

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

Please bear with me, I've been working with XCode/IOS for a day, so you may need to explain things...

The error I get is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, s` <-- I can't see any more than that.

It happens when I set the `categoryBitMask` here:

```
    var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Alien")       
    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: alien.texture, size: alien.size)
    alien.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = alienCategory // <-- Here
```

It doesn't always happen, it seems to happen when the second "Alien" is spawned (a new one is spawned every second).

Here is a link to the project as it stands right now:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1npctvb99vw2l7x/BubbleBurst.zip

Any help you could give me on this, even just telling how what to google for (I spent three hours searching and found nothing of use), would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I have resolved the issue but i do not know the exact issue.It is related with conversion to `UInt to Int`
First it is coming in `iPhone 5` simulator not `iPhone 5s` i am using Xcode Beta5.

Second the runtime exception is coming in different line than it is showing.

I think this problem is related with `arc4random` as it gives 32 bit integer so might be something going on.But if you change below code with yours it will not throw error.I have converted all to `UInt32`

```
    let minimumDuration:UInt32 = 2
    let maximumDuration:UInt32 = 4
    let rangeDuration:UInt32 = maximumDuration - minimumDuration
    println("range\(rangeDuration)")
    let duration = arc4random() % rangeDuration + minimumDuration


    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))
```

Also you are not taking care of optionals.In this line in `didBeginContact` `firstBody.node` or `seconBody.node` is nil when you fire and it collide with your body.

So it throws exception at runtime of `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in below line

```
 torpedodidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: seconBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
```

Put this in if condition and check if it is nil or not

```
if firstBody.node != nil && seconBody.node != nil {
   torpedodidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: seconBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
}
```

Final method will be below.Replace this method with yours

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {

    if (contact != nil && contact.bodyA != nil && contact.bodyB != nil)
    {
        var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
        var seconBody:SKPhysicsBody

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            seconBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            seconBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & torpedoCategory != 0 && seconBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory != 0)
        {

            if firstBody.node != nil && seconBody.node != nil {
            torpedodidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: seconBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just replaced my method with yours.  I still get the same error I listed before.  Note, I'm using XCode6-Beta5.

Comment: @Vijay I am also testing your code on xcode6-Beta5.I have found only one error.Can you give me line no on which you getting the error

Comment: @Vijay running your code on PHone5s simulator not giving the error you listed but on iPhone 5 it is giving the error.

Comment: @Vijay I have edited my answer i do not know exxact reason but by replacing my code it will not throw error

Comment: You are right, with ihone 5s this error doesn't happen.